# Finding an antiderivative of $f(x) = x^{-1}$ not taking any positive value in the interval $1 \leq x \leq 2$

Tags: calculus

There will be some antiderivative of $f() = ^{−1}$ 
not taking any positive value in the
interval $1 \leq x \leq 2$?

Justify your answer

Here I have some problems with the understanding of the problem

The antiderivative of $x^{−1}$ is $\ln |x|+C$

Here comes the problem I don´t know if it want to know where $C$ value give a negative value like...

$\ln |x|-2$

All the values will be negative and accomplish the instruction...

---

This is other interpretation

$f(x)=^{−1}$

first antiderivative is $\ln |x|+C$

second antiderivative is $x\ln(x)-x+C$

In the second antiderivative all values are negative

Which one is correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I like the first answer

Comment: But, what can I justify it?

Comment: "An antiderivative" almost always means "One particular choice for the constant $C$ for the (first) antiderivative". But the ultimate judge will be whoever wrote that problem text. Also note that the second antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is $x\ln |x| + Cx + D$.

Comment: You could justify the first answer by showing that if $1\le x\le 2$ then $\ln x-2\le0$ and it's an anti-derivative

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The second interpretation is unlikely. It should have said iterated antiderivative or higher-order antiderivative or similar. In addition, there *is* a solution for the straight antiderivative.